# Duplicate values on join linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having some problem with the results, I get duplicates instead of two with different values on the join. The db contains those two values but one of them has different value inside the text field, how come I get duplicates, the only thing that is same is the CompanyPageId).

```
 var query = (from pageEducation in _context.PageEducations
            join companyPage in _context.Pages on pageEducation.CompanyPageId equals companyPage.Id into p
            from companyPage in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where pageEducation.PageId == pageId
            select new PageEducation
            {
                Id = pageEducation.Id,
                PageId = pageEducation.PageId,
                CompanyPageId = pageEducation.CompanyPageId,
                CustomCompany = pageEducation.CustomCompany,
                CompanyPage = companyPage != null ? new Page {Name = companyPage.Name, Id = companyPage.Id} : null,
                Education = pageEducation.Education
            }).ToList();
```

My table looks like this:

```
CompanyPageId, education
33             edu1
33             edu2
```

and the result is list with two items but duplicates.

WHen i run this query in SQL i dont get any duplicates:

```
select * from Page_Educations
left join Pages on page_Educations.CompanyPageId = pages.Id                
where page_Educations.PageId = 10
```

It even working when I run the linq in LinqPad

```
 var query = from pageEducation in Page_Educations
            join companyPage in Pages on pageEducation.CompanyPageId equals companyPage.ID into p
            from companyPage in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where pageEducation.PageId == 10
            select new 
            {
                Id = pageEducation.Id,
                PageId = pageEducation.PageId,
                CompanyPageId = pageEducation.CompanyPageId,
                CustomCompany = pageEducation.CustomCompany,
                CompanyPage = companyPage != null ? new {Name = companyPage.Name, Id = companyPage.ID} : null,
                Education = pageEducation.Education
            };

       query.Dump();
```

Comment: Duplicate results usually indicate mismatches in primary keys between db and EF class model.

Comment: @GertArnold - Thx for your response. Do you know how I can I solve it ?

Comment: No, this is something you've got to check.

Comment: Ok, I am kind of lost here .. I have checked the Context and both classes hasKey(p => p.Id)

Comment: And what about the database?

Comment: both tables has Id as PrimaryKey